# How can I override ToString in multi constructor with 2d array?

Tags: c#, arrays

A question from a C# beginner that can't find the solution in web.

Here is a constructor with an 2d array

> public MineSweeperBoard()
>          {
>              // new board
>              board = new BoardItem[MineSweeper_Constants.RowNum, >MineSweeper_Constants.ColNum];
>              // put mines and set value
>              InitialiseBoard();
>          }

```
private BoardItem [,] board;
```

`board.ToString` is not working that it return the type instead of override it.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string a = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < MineSweeper_Constants.ColNum; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MineSweeper_Constants.RowNum; i++)
        {
            a += board[i, j].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is another constructor BoardItem:

```
public BoardItem(char a)
{
    this.itemContents = a;
    this.visibleItemContents = ProjectTwo.MineSweeper_Constants.character[10];
}
```

Here `BoardItem.ToString()` is working.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    char[] b = new char[1];
    b[0] = GetVisibleItemContents();
    string a = new string(b);
    return a;            
}
```

How can I print the string of board with override ToString(my teacher said I must use this)?

```
>{
>    class BoardItem
>    {
>        readonly char itemContents;
>        char visibleItemContents;
>
>        public BoardItem(char a)
>        {
>            // 1. The actual contents of the item (use Minesweeper_Constants) 
>            this.itemContents = a;
>
>            // 2. The visible contents of the item (use Minesweeper_Constants) and set to >unknown
>            this.visibleItemContents = ProjectTwo.MineSweeper_Constants.character[10];
>        }
>
>        public char GetItemContents()
>        {
>            return this.itemContents;
>        }
>
>        public override string ToString()
>        {
>                char[] b = new char[1];
>               b[0] = GetVisibleItemContents();
>                string a = new string(b);
>                return a;
>            
>        }
>   
>    }
>}
>
```

another class

```
enter code here

>    class MineSweeperBoard
>    {
>        private BoardItem [,] board;
>        protected static int[,] mineLocation;
>        protected static int numberOfMine;
>public MineSweeperBoard()
>        {
>            // new board
>            board = new BoardItem[MineSweeper_Constants.RowNum, >MineSweeper_Constants.ColNum];
>            // put mines and set value
>            InitialiseBoard();            
>        }
>public override string ToString()
>{
>    string a = "";
>    for (int j = 0; j < MineSweeper_Constants.ColNum; j++)
>    {
>        for (int i = 0; i < MineSweeper_Constants.RowNum; i++)
>        {
>            a += board[i, j].ToString();
>        }
>    }
>}
```

main class:

```
enter code here

>static void Main(string[] args){
>GameLoop()
>}
>GameLoop(){
MineSweeperBoard board = new MineSweeperBoard();
>Console.WriteLine(board.ToString());
>}
```

Comment: You'd have to encapsulate the board into a class and then you may override ToString()

Comment: `private BoardItem [,] board;` is not a constructor, it's a field. How does your class look like where this field is inside?

Comment: Could you please post more of your code? It is hard to guess the problem that we don't see it all. Or just more of it.

Comment: I'm not sure how that compiles since your ToString method doesn't return a string!  You need to add `return a;` to your ToString method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Board
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            // Create the board
            Board b = new Board();
            // Print the maze
            Console.Write(b.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Board
    {
        private BoardItem[,] items = new BoardItem[10, 10];

        // Board contructor - populate the multidimensional array - do you own login here to populate the cells.
        public Board()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {                        
                    items[i, j] = new BoardItem();
                }
            }
        }

        // Print each cell from the MineSweeper
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string ret = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    ret += items[i, j].ToString();
                }
                ret += Environment.NewLine;
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }

    class BoardItem
    {
        char BoardItemCharToPriint = '-';

        // Print the current cell
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return BoardItemCharToPriint.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I created a Board class encapsualting the board items. Each class has it's ToString() method overridden. If you go something like this you can make your task as your teacher wanted, by overriding the ToString methods.

Comment: It might be better to use a `StringBuilder` object instead of string concatenation inside the `ToString()` method.

Comment: Yeah, that is right. This is just a scratch, there are many things to be changed yet. This is just an example, a scratch.